# Difference between camcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth/videoFrameHeight and Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()

Tags: android, camera, mediarecorder

I want to create a video only recording app on HTC Thunderbolt, and I am trying to find a high quality setting to record. I am very confused which setting to choose the size from.

```
1. CamcorderProfile.videoFrameWidth/Height 
2. Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()
```

I read the value from the device. Here they are:

```
1. CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH) returns:

   videoFrameWidth: 720
   videoFrameHeight: 480

2. Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes() returns:

   Camera supported preview width = 800 height = 480
   Camera supported preview width = 640 height = 480
   Camera supported preview width = 640 height = 384
```

Now if I use the value from

```
1. By calling MediaRecorder.setVideoSize(720,480), I got an error when I try to start recording. (E/MediaRecorder(4446): start failed: -16), 
2. By calling MediaRecorder.setVideoSize(800,480), it works fine.
```

I am very confused which setting to use. In addition, there are 2 other functions

```
3. Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes() 

4. Camera.Parameters.getSupportedVideoSizes()
```

I don't understand the relationship between those functions, and which one to use for what purpose. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks,
Howy

Comment: "preview" is the live preview video you can see, "video" the one you can record and "picture" if you take still images

Answer (score 0):

In Android API version 11 and above, there is a function called `getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo()`.

So the right thing to do is to use that API to query the preview size, use that preview size, then record based on that size.

It seems that API version 10 and below do not have such a thing, therefore, Android camera is deeply fragmented.